# How to avoid mobs?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

First when I started playing Minecraft PE I turned on peaceful mode, but then I got tired of it and decided to switch on hard. However since it is Pocket Edition there are only 2 options: peaceful and hard. When I just started hard I saw a creeper and freaked out even though I was in my house. I hate creepers which can kill me without me knowing it as they can explode from a distance. Is there a way to avoid being killed by mobs in hard difficulty?

Comment: With or without cheating? Why would you change to a mode that contains creatures that can kill you when you do not want to be killed?

Answer (score 1):

There are no 'special' ways of avoiding mods on the PE version. The same tactics that work for the 'full' Micecraft game work here too.

There are numerous links about this, but [this one seems most suitable at the moment](http://www.gameyum.com/minecraft/123261-jeepers-creepers-how-to-deal-with-creepers/).